# MPI_Isend and MPI_Irecv seem to be causing a deadlock

Tags: c, mpi, parallel-processing, hpc, openmpi

I'm using non-blocking communication in MPI to send various messages between processes. However, I appear to be getting a deadlock. I have used PADB ([see here](http://padb.pittman.org.uk/)) to look at the message queues and have got the following output:

```
1:msg12: Operation 1 (pending_receive) status 0 (pending)
1:msg12: Rank local 4 global 4
1:msg12: Size desired 4
1:msg12: tag_wild 0
1:msg12: Tag desired 16
1:msg12: system_buffer 0
1:msg12: Buffer 0xcaad32c
1:msg12: 'Receive: 0xcac3c80'
1:msg12: 'Data: 4 * MPI_FLOAT'
--
1:msg32: Operation 0 (pending_send) status 2 (complete)
1:msg32: Rank local 4 global 4
1:msg32: Actual local 4 global 4
1:msg32: Size desired 4 actual 4
1:msg32: tag_wild 0
1:msg32: Tag desired 16 actual 16
1:msg32: system_buffer 0
1:msg32: Buffer 0xcaad32c
1:msg32: 'Send: 0xcab7c00'
1:msg32: 'Data transfer completed'
--
2:msg5: Operation 1 (pending_receive) status 0 (pending)
2:msg5: Rank local 1 global 1
2:msg5: Size desired 4
2:msg5: tag_wild 0
2:msg5: Tag desired 16
2:msg5: system_buffer 0
2:msg5: Buffer 0xabbc348
2:msg5: 'Receive: 0xabd1780'
2:msg5: 'Data: 4 * MPI_FLOAT'
--
2:msg25: Operation 0 (pending_send) status 2 (complete)
2:msg25: Rank local 1 global 1
2:msg25: Actual local 1 global 1
2:msg25: Size desired 4 actual 4
2:msg25: tag_wild 0
2:msg25: Tag desired 16 actual 16
2:msg25: system_buffer 0
2:msg25: Buffer 0xabbc348
2:msg25: 'Send: 0xabc5700'
2:msg25: 'Data transfer completed'
```

This seems to have showed that sends have completed, but all of the receives are pending (the above is just an small part of the log for a tag value of 16). However, how can this happen? Surely sends can't complete without the associated receive completing, as in MPI all sends and receives have to match. At least that's what I thought...

Can anyone provide any insights?

I can provide the code I'm using to do this, but surely Isend and Irecv should work regardless of what order they are all called in, assuming that MPI_Waitall is called right at the end.

**Update:** Code is available at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/909004)

**Update:** I've made various modifications to the code, but it still isn't working quite properly. The new code is at [the same gist](https://gist.github.com/909004), and the output I'm getting is at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/910543). I have a number of questions/issues with this code:

1. Why is the output from the final loop (printing all of the arrays) interspersed with the rest of the output when I have a MPI_Barrier() before it to make sure all of the work has been done before printing it out?
2. It is possible/sensible to be sending from rank 0 to rank 0 - will that work ok? (assuming a correct matching receive is posted, of course).
3. I'm getting lots of very strange long numbers in the output, which I assume is some kinda of memory-overwriting problem, or sizes of variables problem. The interesting thing is that this must be resulting from the MPI communications, because I initialise new_array to a value of 9999.99 and the communication obviously causes it to be changed to these strange values. Any ideas why?

Overall it seems that some of the transposition is occurring (bits of the matrix seem to be transposed...), but definitely not all of it - it's these strange numbers that are coming up that are worrying me the most!

Comment: A send can complete before the matching recieve has completed, and that's _certainly_ true with non-blocking sends and receives.   I don't think there's any alternative here to seeing the code.   I can think of lots of ways to launch a bunch of isends, irecvs, and and have them hang forever, even with only one epoch of sending and waitall.

Comment: Well your code is obviously wrong somewhere, I suggest you post it. :)

Comment: Thanks for the responses. The code is available at https://gist.github.com/909004, as it is fairly long, and I thought that most of it might be fairly important. It's trying to transpose a distributed matrix (I know it might not be the best way to approach it, but I'd like to get it to work).

Comment: I've now posted another update - after doing modifications based on advice from the response below (and other issues that I've realised). Hopefully we can get to the bottom of this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `MPI_Isend` and `MPI_Irecv` you have to be sure to not modify the buffers before you wait for the request to complete, and you are definitely violating this. What if you had the recieves all go into a second matrix instead of doing it in place?

Also, `global_x2 * global_y2` is your tag, but I'm not sure that it will be unique for every send-recieve pair, which could be messing things up. What happens if you switch it to sending tag `(global_y2 * global_columns) + global_x2` and recieving tag `(global_x2 * global_columns) + global_y2`.

Edit: As for your question about output, I'm assuming you are testing this by running all your processes on the same machine and just looking at the standard output. When you do it this way, your output gets buffered oddly by the terminal, even though the printf code all executes before the barrier. There are two ways I get around this. You could either print to a separate file for each process, or you could send your output as messages to process 0 and let him do all the actual printing.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've tried those (I'd realised the first problem already) but they don't seem to have completely sorted it. I can now run it without it deadlocking, but the transposition isn't happening properly. I've altered the question to put links to the code (as it is now) and the output I'm getting. I'm a little confused about a number of things - my barriers don't seem to be working, and I'm wondering whether sending something from (for example) rank 0 to rank 0 and expecting it to work is a bad idea...